# Storing random strings without duplicates in a database

Tags: java, string, random

I am generating strings to use as IDs, so to avoid repetitions I must currently check in my database if that string has already been assigned and if so, generate another one, what I want is avoid the rework of calculating another string.

I can generate and store all possible strings to assign them more quickly but I am not convinced by this idea

Can you think of something more efficient?

I edit: the requirement demands that I use identifiers of this type, nothing personal;)

The lifetime of each ID is 24 hours

Comment: `Remove a string after it has been chosen.`

Comment: How long is an id? Do an id has a specific format like `XXX###` where X is a letter and # is a digit or is it a sequence of random chars?  Is the range `A-Z` or just the two chars `AZ` ?

Comment: You could use a Map (maybe a HashMap) to store the ids you've used. Store the string along with a datetime so you can clean them out when they've expired.

Comment: note that the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) is useful for working out how much state you need to store.  i.e. this is why @rzwitserloot says you need 128 bits, it's enough to make it unlikely to see any collision until you start storing near to 2^64 identifiers

Answer (score 0):

This is an *extremely* common problem. Your strategy sounds like a very bad way to go about it. Surely you didn't mean to actually do this.

### Use the right tool for the job: Let the database solve this problem

Databases have the notion of sequences / auto-incrementing primary keys. The database will just... take care of it. Whenever you add a row to a database, just don't specify any ID at all, and the db will generate one for you, and it will be guaranteed unique. Just about every DB has trivial syntax for this as part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement, for example `CREATE TABLE foo (id SERIAL);`.

### Use the right tool for the job: Indices

Make the ID either the primary key, or otherwise tell the database you want it to be unique (in some DBs, you add a 'UNIQUE' constraint. In others, you add an index for that column using `CREATE INDEX` and specify that it needs to be DISTINCT or UNIQUE - these are areas where databases haven't standardized on SQL syntax much, and you didn't mention which database engine you are using here. It won't be hard to look online for instructions).

Once you have done this and you attempt to add a row with an ID you've already used before, the statement will simply fail. You can catch this SQLException and then just start over and generate a different one at random. The database is using an indexed check, which is quite fast.

### Use the right tool for the job: UUID

The problem of "I want to generate an ID quickly and nevertheless rest assured it is definitely, absolutely, unique" So common, it has been solved already. Meet the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Java has an [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) for it, and many [databases support it natively](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-uuid.html). So make your column type `UUID` and not `VARCHAR`.

Yes, they are large. If you want speed and guarantees, it needs to be large enough that the stochastic odds of randomness producing the same ID to be so low, that generating one ID every second for the rest of the lifetime of the universe still won't cause 2 identical ones unless you get *very* unlucky (0.000000000000000001% level unlucky), you need to throw more bits at the problem. 128 to be precise.